# Compile 64-bit Mac app with py2app

Tags: python, macos, 64-bit, screensaver, py2app

I've compiled a [Python screen saver](http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/examples/pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver/index.html) on my Mac OS X 10.7 using py2app 0.6.3, but when I open the screen saver in System Preferences i get the following message:

> You cannot use the Silly Balls screen saver on this computer.

I've read that this message means it needs to be compiled for 64-bit.

I'm running Python 2.7.1 64-bit on a 64-bit system.

#### How can I compile a 64-bit app with py2app that makes the screen saver example work?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm having the same problem.  Also see my comment under Michael's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this - note 'LSArchitecturePriority' : 'x86_64',

```
#cat ./setup.py 
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

APP = ['YourApp.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': False,
    'semi_standalone':'False',
    'optimize': 2,
    'includes': [
        ...
    ],
    'site_packages': 'True',
    'plist' : {
        'LSPrefersPPC' : False,
        'LSArchitecturePriority' : 'x86_64',
    }
}

setup(
    name = "YourApp",
    version = "0.0.4",
    author = "Iam",
    author_email = "info@test.com",
    description = ("An demonstration of how to create, document, and publish MacOS app"),
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and adding the LSArchitecturePriority option didn't do the trick for me.  Does anyone have any other guesses?  I found this link: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1666/_index.html but I'm not sure how to apply that suggestion to my setup.py file.

Comment: Sorry, @Jason, I didn't. I wrote to Ronald Oussoren (the main PyObjC developer), in [this email thread](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythonmac-sig/2012-December/023796.html). The issue seems to be that in OS 10.6 and OS 10.7, Apple's screensaver framework requires your code to be built with garbage collection enabled, but PyObjC doesn't support GC.

Comment: Furthermore, Apple has now changed their mind about GC. Newer frameworks (including the screensaver framework in 10.8) don't use it, so it would be a waste of time to add GC support to PyObjC at this point. Bottom line: PyObjC screensavers don't work in 10.6 and 10.7, but 10.5 and 10.8 should work (I personally haven't tried, though).

Comment: Thanks @superbatfish. I tried running [the SillyBalls demo](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc/src/78d315181dd4d7c7c18f366af5d7afb3b8583013/pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver/Examples/SillyBallsSaver?at=default) on OSX 10.8.3 and had no luck. Maybe I'll follow up with Ron or the mailing list.

Comment: I contacted Jason Toffaletti, the developer of SillyBalls, and he's no longer working on osx development. So, no help there.